# How to Check whether camera is open for capture image or to record video in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my app, Application allow user to capture image/record video. But I don't know how to check the result in below method.

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {
}
```

Your solutions are always appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what you need:

```
 - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        // Media is an image

        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || [mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Media is a video
        // Video URL
        NSURL *localUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    }
}
```